# Migrating Apache configuration from 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: wordpress, apache, security, bitnami

I am using this Apache conf to lock down **/wp-admin/** area with login/password, but I am not sure if my new Apache 2.4 conf parts are correct, can someone help me?

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-admin">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted files"
    AuthUserFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/wordpress_users"
    Require valid-user

    # Apache 2.2
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        <Files admin-ajax.php>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Satisfy any
        </Files>
    </IfModule>

    # Apache 2.4
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
        <Files admin-ajax.php>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </IfModule>    
</Directory>
```

Comment: Did you test the new configuration?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working. But the question is whether the # Apache 2.2 and # Apache 2.4 blocks are correct.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Apache Configuration file did you modify? Are you introducing the changes in the file **/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf**? Please use this file if you're using a different one.

`AuthUserFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/wordpress_users"`

Does this files exist? Did you create it using **htpasswd**? Please find the whole documentaion in the link below:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html

I would also add the line below to explain why you don't allow the access to certain files:

`ErrorDocument 403 "For security reasons, this file is not accessible."`

Remember to restart Apache to load all the changes by running the command:

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

Comment: Yes, I am editing opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf file and I already set up the htpasswd too.

Comment: My problem is if  # Apache 2.2 and # Apache 2.4 blocks have correct directives...

Comment: I don't see anything weird in those directives. You are simply limiting the access so `admin-ajax.php` is the only file accesible. 

Remember, you can always remove them if they are not working as you expect :)